# sql server :Insert Multiple records in two tables in the same moment

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have two tables employee and employeeDetails and the relation between two tables is one to one, i want after insert all records on employee table get all Id's and insert it on employeeDetails table.

I have query select from xml and insert into table employee

```
my query:
INSERT INTO employee
SELECT ID,Name, Salary
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'employees/employee') // file contains 50000 record
WITH 
(
ID int 'ID',
Name [varchar](50) 'Name',
Salary money 'Salary',  
)
```

**but i don't want use triggers**

Comment: Why are there two tables, if the second table is just duplicating data from the first? What's the motivation behind this design?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever more details about employee in emloyee1

Comment: If one of the tables is an extension of the other, then use foreign keys. Do not duplicate data.

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper yes i wand to do this solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
declare @Temp table(
   id int
   )

INSERT INTO employee OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @Temp
SELECT ID,Name, Salary
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'employees/employee') // file contains 50000 record
WITH 
(
ID int 'ID',
Name [varchar](50) 'Name',
Salary money 'Salary',  
)

insert into employeeDetails
   select * from @Temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Use any type of TEMP table within a Transaction, Below I am using a TABLE VARIABLE in SQL Server, but you can simply create a #TEMP table also.  Put your 50000+ rows in @TEMP_EMPLOYEE table so that they are not mixed with existing data, then simply insert rows from @TEMP_EMPLOYEE table into both EMPLOYEE and EMPLOYEE1 table.

This answer is for your Original Question with no mention of IDENTITY columns or FOREIGN KEYS.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   DECLARE @TEMP_EMPLOYEE TABLE
   (
     Id INT, 
     Name VARCHAR(50),
     Salary MONEY
   )

   INSERT INTO @TEMP_EMPLOYEE
   SELECT ID,Name, Salary
      FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'employees/employee') -- file contains 50000 record
   WITH 
   (
      Id INT 'ID',
      Name [varchar](50) 'Name',
      Salary money 'Salary'
   )

   INSERT INTO employee  SELECT Id, Name, Salary FROM @TEMP_EMPLOYEE
   INSERT INTO employee1 SELECT Id, Name, Salary FROM @TEMP_EMPLOYEE

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

If however, if I understand your comments correctly if the EMPLOYEE table has the IDENTITY column ID, and the EMPLOYEE1 table has the FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINST on ID column to the first EMPLOYEE table, then you can do the following using a CURSOR and SCOPE_IDENTITY.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   DECLARE @TEMP_EMPLOYEE TABLE
   (
     Id INT, 
     Name VARCHAR(50),
     Salary MONEY
   )

   INSERT INTO @TEMP_EMPLOYEE
   SELECT ID,Name, Salary
      FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'employees/employee') -- file contains 50000 record
   WITH 
   (
      Id INT 'ID',
      Name [varchar](50) 'Name',
      Salary money 'Salary'
   )

   DECLARE @CURSOR_ID INT
   DECLARE @CURSOR_NAME VARCHAR(50)
   DECLARE @CURSOR_SALARY MONEY
   DECLARE @IDENT_ID INT

   DECLARE EmployeeCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT [Id], [Name], [Salary] FROM @TEMP_EMPLOYEE
   OPEN EmployeeCursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM EmployeeCursor INTO @CURSOR_ID,@CURSOR_NAME, @CURSOR_SALARY
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      -- Table with the Identity Column
      INSERT INTO Employee(Name, Salary) VALUES(@CURSOR_NAME, @CURSOR_SALARY)
      SELECT @IDENT_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
      --Table with the Foreign Key Column
      INSERT INTO Employee1(Id, Name, Salary) VALUES(@IDENT_ID, @CURSOR_NAME,     @CURSOR_SALARY)
      FETCH NEXT FROM EmployeeCursor INTO @CURSOR_ID,@CURSOR_NAME, @CURSOR_SALARY
   END
   CLOSE EmployeeCursor
   DEALLOCATE EmployeeCursor

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: but employee id is IDENTITY and Relation one to one

Comment: Please explain why you think the answer should be changed and let the one who posted it update it (unless is is a minor edit).

Comment: because id of employee is IDENTITY and i cant insert it on temp_employee table i want insert records in employee and get inserted ids

Comment: @user3152935 please add the table definitions to your question.  If employee table with column ID is an IDENTITY, then in your question you are inserting into that column ID, which is not correct and misleading.  Nor do you have anywhere in your question IDENTITY columns.

Comment: My answer applies only to your original question with no mention of IDENTITY or FOREIGN KEYS.  So mention if one table has a foreign key to the other, and which tables or both has the IDENTITY, which you do not mention in your question, those are very critical pieces of information.  Then I can answer that.

Comment: If you have an IDENTITY on one of the tables and FOREIGN KEY on the other, then DECLARE a CURSOR selecting from the TEMP table, insert each row into the table with IDENTITY, SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY then insert the same row into your FOREIGN KEY table.  All rows will be done in the CURSOR.  You should be all set with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to select data from employee to employee1.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: this is bulk insert of 5000 record i can't use SCOPE_IDENTITY()